# Meteor-React: How to re-render on a state inside setState after Meteor.call callback finishes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react, meteor-methods

Event summary:
I click edit button.
editForm() displays the form using this.setState() and this.state inside render().
The setState() above has the {this.state} as a value that I need to display.
Once I click update button inside the form, updateMessage() activates, which Meteor.call that includes a callback option.
This callback function has this.setState() that connects to that {this.state} I mentioned above.

So how do I make that {this.state} display after Meteor.call() callback and setState()?

*-note-* putting that {this.state} inside render() will display after callback.

Heres the code: *this.state.show_error_or_noerror* inside editMessage() is what I need to display.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

    const messageContent = this.props.messageContent;
    const username = this.props.username;
    const articleTitle = this.props.articleTitle;

    this.state = {
      show_error_or_noerror: '',
      messageContent: messageContent,
      username: username,
      articleTitle: articleTitle
    };

    this.editMessage = this.editMessage.bind(this);
    this.updateMessage = this.updateMessage.bind(this);

  }
  updateMessage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const messageId = this.props.messageId;
    const messageContent = this.refMessage.value.trim();

    Meteor.call('message.update', messageId, messageContent, (error) => {
      if(error) {
        this.setState({show_error_or_noerror: error.reason});
      } else {
        this.setState({show_error_or_noerror: 'Updated successfully.'});
      }
    });
  }
  editMessage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const messageId = this.props.messageId;

    this.setState({
      ['show_form'+messageId]: <form onSubmit={this.updateMessage}>
        <textarea
          ref={(textarea) => {this.refMessage = textarea;}}
          defaultValue={this.state.messageContent}
        />
        <h6>by {this.state.username}</h6>
        <h6>Article: {this.state.articleTitle}</h6>
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
        <button onClick={this.hideForm}>Hide</button>
        {this.state.show_error_or_noerror}
      </form>
    });
  }
  render() {
    const messageId = this.props.messageId;

    return (
      <span className="message_updator">
        <button onClick={this.editMessage}>Edit</button>
        {this.state['show_form'+messageId]}
      </span>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve reactivity in meteor, create a Tracker.dependency object and have your render depend on it ([ref](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency)).

Create a dependency in your constructor

```
var dep = new Tracker.Dependency;
```

And have your render depend on it

```
dep.depend();
```

And call this in your setState function

```
dep.changed();
```

Comment: I put `dep = new Tracker.Dependency;` as a global variable inside constructor. <br/> I put `dep.depend();` inside render(). <br/> I put `dep.changed()` inside `if else` statements of `Meteor.call` callback. <br/> Noting changed.

Comment: I think the issue is with Meteor.call designed to only run once. Here's two packages for reactive meteor calls [meteor-reactive-method](https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-reactive-method) and [meteor-call](https://github.com/mnmtanish/meteor-call/)

Comment: I removed `Meteor.call()` and only used `this.setState()`. it still did not rerender, so it is not a Meteor issue. I fixed it using react.